# Efficiently execute mathematical Python expression in C++ many

Tags: python, c++, math

I have a python program, that generates a mathematical expression like

```
exp(sin(x-y))**2
```

Now I want to give this to my C++ program, that must evaluate this expression with different x,y values. My first approach was to use the Python.h library with PyRun_String.

Here the initialization code:

```
func=function;
Py_Initialize();
    memset(pythonString,0,strlen(pythonString));

    // add whiteNoise Kernel
    sprintf(pythonString,"from math import *;func=lambda x,y:(%s+0.1*(x==y))",function);
    //printf("%s\n",pythonString);
    PyRun_SimpleString(pythonString);
```

and here the code that gets evaluated many times:

```
char execString[200];
memset(execString,0,strlen(execString));

sprintf(execString,"result=func(%f,%f)",x1[0],  x2[0]);

PyObject* main = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
PyObject* globalDictionary = PyModule_GetDict(main);
PyObject* localDictionary = PyDict_New();

//create the dictionaries as shown above

PyRun_String(execString, Py_file_input, globalDictionary, localDictionary);
double result = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyDict_GetItemString(localDictionary, "result"));
```

However, I think it's really too slow to parse the string with PyRun_String every time again. Is there a way to directly convert Python expressions to a C++ function, that can be invoked efficiently? Or is there any alternative? It would also be okay to use something like symbolicc++

Comment: This is kind of irrelevant to the question but... Have you tried to see if pypy delivers the necessary performance before jumping to heavyweight c->python programming?

Comment: i dont know if this helps but i have an [xpresion engine for python](https://github.com/foo123/Xpresion) which can be used to generate C++ source code for the evaluation expression (actually it can generate any code you define)

Comment: @NikosM. this seems to be pretty useful. I will give it a try :)

Comment: @XapaJIaMnu   No I didn't try it, I assumed it would not run as the python code uses proprietary libraries

Comment: Note that you will need to override the Xpresion class to just return the source code and not generate an evaluator as it will be C++ source code and not python code, but the rest is straight forward, if you need any help you can add an issue on  github, cheers

Comment: @jarCrack yeah, it might not run, but if you decide to spend time on it, you should be able to get it to work. I am not sure if it is worth it though if that is the case maybe the xpression engine is a better solution.

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be Python code or would some [C++ mathematical expression library](https://fastmathparser.codeplex.com/) do the job as well? [(or see here)](http://www.partow.net/programming/exprtk/)

Comment: Why don't you try using `Cython` or `NumPy` if all you want is speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to pass all your inputs as arrays/vectors to your c++ & get all solved at once. Also, try `Py_CompileString` & `PyEval_EvalCode` instead of `PyRun_String`. I had to solve millions of equations & found a 10X speed improvement.

Below is an example for a simple `'a + b'` but with some more for loops one can generalize it for any equation with any number of variables. For a million values below is done in slightly less than a second on my machine (compared to 10 seconds for `PyRun_String`).

```
PyObject* main = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
PyObject* globalDict = PyModule_GetDict(main);
PyCodeObject* code = (PyCodeObject*) Py_CompileString("a + b", "My Eqn", Py_eval_input);
for (millions of values in input) {
    PyObject* localDict = PyDict_New();
    PyObject* oA = PyFloat_FromDouble(a);  // 'a' from input
    PyObject* oB = PyFloat_FromDouble(b);  // 'b' from input
    PyDict_SetItemString(localDict, "a", oA);
    PyDict_SetItemString(localDict, "b", oB);
    PyObject* pyRes = PyEval_EvalCode(code, globalDict, localDict);
    r = PyFloat_AsDouble(pyRes);
    // put r in output array

    Py_DECREF(pyRes);
    Py_DECREF(localDict)
}
Py_DECREF(code);
```